# User input determining what my SQL table result will look like

Tags: php, sql, database

```
 <form id="well" class="well span6" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="display.php" method="post">
                Category:<select name="category">
                    <option value="*">All</option>
                    <option value="art">Art</option>
                    <option value="crafts">Craft</option>
                    <option value="cosplay">Cosplay</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option></select></br>


             # Of Images:<select name="numofimg">
                    <option value="100000">All</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option></br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Display">
            </form>
```

This is my form there's 2 results i want to take from this category & number of images to display.

This isn't what i want to do but this is a result i got working but it opens another page

```
$cat=$_POST['category'];
$limit=$_POST['numofimg'];

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE category = '$cat' LIMIT $limit ") or die(mysql_error());
```

This works and takes the user input and outputs the results I need, but this does it on a different page which I can't have happen I need the results to be displayed on my page where the form is. I'm not very good with AJAX or JQuery and can't find any specific guides to what I've been trying to achieve.

If there is any other work around to this I will be very grateful I've been scouring hundreds of pages and suggestions and really just can't do it.

Comment: You are going to have to persevere with learning AJAX, and jquery will make it easier.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP. You should consider using the `MySQLi` library or `PDO` extension instead. Also, *never* run a query using user input without properly escaping it. If the user submitted a request with a single apostrophe, your query would be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: If you don't want to use AJAX, why not just put the form and the results on the same page? i.e. remove the `action` attribute, and put that PHP below the form, wrapped in an `if ($_POST) { }` block. The page will reload but the form will stay there. Another crappier way to do it would be to place an iframe on the page and set your form's `target` to that iframe.

Comment: What M Miller is eluding to is called PHP redux. Here is a link that should help. http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=412368&seqNum=2

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server totally pwn3d.